# Downspout repair (with the 6 inch section)

Tags: gutters, downspout

I cut a 6 inch section out of a 3x4 inch downspout. How can i put it back together?  I was installing a rain diverter and placed it too high. Thought about using 2 adapters but having trouble finding them at that 3x4 size. Should i just buy a whole new downspout?

Answer (score 1):

You can crimp your own ends with a crimping pliers available at most home stores in the heating duct work section or hand tools section. They are simple to use and not expensive to purchase. When using these for splicing you will lose 1 1/2" - 3" of overall length though so keep that in mind when deciding whether to replace the whole downspout or repairing it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the fluted end so you can lap the sections properly. This will probably require that you purchase a new length of spout.